# Add object to an existing lattice deformer Maya

Tags: python, maya, lattice, pymel

I’m currently stuck with as silly problem.

I’m writing a re-build script for one of the characters and I need to write a command in python Maya to add a model to already existing lattice deformer. Is there a way to do this? I know that if I were to do it manually, I could add new object via deformer set, are there any other ways or simpler even ways.

Thank you in advance for any advice

Answer (score 1):

here you go :

```
mySel = ['objectName']
deformer = 'latticeName'
myLatticeSet = cmds.listConnections( deformer, type="objectSet" )
cmds.sets( mySel, add= myLatticeSet[0] )
```